# Отличие ViewBag от ViewData

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

Зачем существуют и *ViewBag* и *ViewData*? Ведь, по сути, они выполняют абсолютно одну и ту же функцию - хранить данные для представления.

Есть ли разница в быстроте загрузки страницы при использовании того или другого?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Копипаст из интернета:

**ViewData**

1. ViewData  — это словарный объект, производный от TempViewDataDictionary;
2. Используется для передачи данных из контроллера в соответствующее представление;
3. Жизненный цикл ограничен текущим запросом;
4. Если происходит redirect, значение  ViewData  превращается в null;
5. Также необходимо осуществлять приведение типов  и  проверять на null, чтобы избежать ошибок;

**ViewBag**

1. ViewBag  — динамическое свойство, представляет собой обертку вокруг  ViewData ,  и  также используется для передачи данных из контроллера в соответствующее представление;
2. Жизненный цикл также ограничивается текущий запросом;
3. При редиректе значение также оборачивается в null;
4. Нет необходимости в приведении типов для получения данных

Так же,  ViewBag  имеет преимущество в том, что можно использовать его свойства Strongly typed-методом, при этом корректность данных будет проверена еще на этапе компиляции/написания кода.

Comment: *"можно использовать его свойства Strongly typed-методом"* - но КАК?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, хороший вопрос, очевидно подразумевается [в источнике](http://shiftoffproblem.com/viewdata-viewbag-tempdata-how-to-do/), с которого скопистен был ответ, точечная нотация. Довольно туманно вышло и сбивает с толку.

Answer (score 7):

ViewBag - это динамический объект-обертка над ViewData. Вся разница - в том, что к первому вы обращаетесь через точку, а ко второму - по индексу. Разница в скорости есть, но несущественная. Используйте то, что удобнее.

Comment: спасибо за ответ) Значит, всё-таки ViewBag чуточку побыстрее?

Comment: Разница d crjhjcnb между ViewData и ViewBag даже меньше, чем накладные расходы на вызов действия у контроллера.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а чем отличается TempData от ViewBag?

Comment: @tCode пожалуйста, задавайте новые вопросы в виде вопросов