# Отображение данных с помощью Partial View

Tags: c#, mvc

Есть 2 модели, пользователи и программы (в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/804775/213987) есть описание моделей). Я хочу отобразить в таблицах все программы из бд, и следом всех пользователей.

Сделал 1 контроллер с 2 экшанами и 2 view.

```
    Context db = new Context();
        public ActionResult Progs()
        {
            IEnumerable<Prog> progs = db.Progs;
            IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users;
            ViewBag.Progs = progs;
            ViewData["Users"] = users;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Users()
        {
            IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Prog);

            return View(users);
        }

    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер строки</th>
            <th>Название программы</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Progs)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@item.Id</th>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@Html.Partial("Users", ViewData["Users"]);

    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.User>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер строки</th>
            <th>Название программы</th>
            <th>Фамилия пользователя</th>
            <th>Программа пользователя</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@item.Id</th>
                <td>@item.Surname</td>
                <td>@item.Age</td>
                <td>@item.Prog.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

View User идёт как partial. И когда вызывается экшен контроллера для программ, отрисоваться должны и юзеры, но так как для юзеров данных нет, то и рисовать не из чего, ведь контроллер юзеров не трогается, как в таких случаях поступают? Пробова из экшена программ через ViewBag передавать ещё и юзеров для отрисовки, но не получилось. МОжет как то можно задействовать экшен юзеров в таком случае? Или это нужно сделать как то подругому? Подскажите пожалуйста, только начинаю изучать mvc.

Comment: Обновил ответ, почитайте его и слинкованные вопросы.

Comment: @AK, как я понял модель CompositeProgsAndUsersViewModel, это viewmodel. Вы не могли бы показать пример как она должна выглядеть ну  сам классс, я что то не до окнца понимаю как делаются viewmodel'и, спасибо заранее.

Comment: Дописал ещё обновление ответ, но на будущее рекомендую не впихивать в один вопрос сразу двадцать тем, продумывайте их тщательно и публикуйте как отдельные топики.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У @Html.Partial() есть перегрузка, в которой можно указать данные, а не только имя представления.

Если вы хотите вывести все программы и для каждой указать всех пользователей этих программ, то вам нужно что-то в духе:

```
public ActionResult ProgsWithUsers()
{
    IEnumerable<Prog> progs = db.Progs.Include(x => x.Users).ToArray();
    return View(progs);
}
```

Во вью:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.Prog>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер строки</th>
            <th>Название программы</th>
            <th>Пользователи</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var program in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@program.Id</th>
                <td>@program.Name</td>
            </tr>
            @if(program.Users.Count() > 0)
            {
                <td>@Html.Partial("Users", program.Users)</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>–</td>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ну и в partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.User>

@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <div>@user.Surname</div>
}
```

Update. Если вам нужно сделать вывод сначала всех программ, а потом всех пользователей, то есть варианты.

Самое очевидный и простой. Выбрать данные в одном экшене:

```
public ActionResult CompositeProgsAndUsers()
{
    IEnumerable<Prog> progs = db.Progs;
    IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users;
    var model = new CompositeProgsAndUsersViewModel 
    {
        Progs = progs,
        Users = users,
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Вью строится на базе модели CompositeProgsAndUsersViewModel и содержит вызов двух частичных:

```
@model IEnumerable<CompositeProgsAndUsersViewModel>

@Html.Partial("Progs", Model.Progs)
@Html.Partial("Users", Model.Users)
```

Чем удобен этот вариант - тем что view получаются тоненькими, точечными и могут быть переиспользованы.

Частичные представления будут иметь в качестве модели IEnumerable и IEnumerable соответственно (напишите сами, принцип вы похоже уже поняли)

Если захотите выводить пользователей с программами - см. выше код с .Include(x => x.Progs).

Также можно отказаться от класса модели и просто запихать всё во вьюбаг (код выше у вас есть, я только не понимаю, что мешало всё положить во ViewBag, а не распихивать то во ViewBag, то в ViewData; возможно есть какие-то ограничения, о которых я уже забыл, потому что не люблю пользоваться viewbag/viewdata - но пока мне такой подход [кажется непоследовательным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453202/213987), вы определитесь либо туда, либо сюда)

Другой вариант - внутри view вызвать action через механизм ChildActionOnly (на мой взгля может быть менее подходящим).

А для asp.net core есть новый способ - через inject (см. [ответ Павла Майорова в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790881/213987)).

Update 2. Ваша конкретная ViewModel будет иметь вид:

```
public class CompositeProgsAndUsersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Prog> Progs { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Я [сторонник написания отдельных ViewModel](http://blog.byndyu.ru/2012/05/viewmodel-domain-model.html), а не использую классы домена в качестве view model'ей.

В качестве примера я всегда привожу модель RegisterViewModel из набора ASP.NET Identity (если у вас в asp.net проекте включена identity - посмотрите код), когда в модели есть поля "пароль" и "подтверждение пароля":

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: AK да это тоже не плохой вариант для вывода, но я хотел немного другого. Хотел просто вывести подряд 2 разные гриды. В первой просто список всех программ, а во второй всех пользователей, с названием программы по каждому пользователю. Т.Е. грубо говоря в первой гриде моделька Prog а во второй гриде моделька User. И хотел что бы было вот как, если я вызову контроллер Users тогда отрисуется только табличка с юзерами, а ессли контроллер программы, тогда отрисуются обе таблички. Вот для чего partial view. Так можно сделать?

Comment: Из моей реализации что я описал, я просто пробовал передать в паршиал вью с помощью вью бага коллекцию моделей пользователя, но так нельзя. Вот поэтому и спрашиваю как можно реализовать, спасибо заранее.

Comment: AK всё получилось, с помощью ViewData передал, сейчас изменю в вопросе код на тот с которым всё отработало так как хотел, но ваш ответ не стирайте пожалуйста, я его приму, пусть останется, тоже полезный вариант. Правда последний столбец поехал немного почему то но с разметкой уж как нибудь разберусь :)

Comment: AK всё добавил свой вариант.