# Отправка картинки на сервер WPF - Web Api Core - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Не совсем понимаю некоторые вещи в веб технологиях... Сейчас тренируюсь и делаю простое приложение для отправки картинок на сервер. Задачу себе расписал такую: Клиент на WPF (без MVVM), просто формочка. Поля: Имя, Фамилия, Отдел и кнопка открыть картинку (загрузка фото человека), ну и время, когда были отправлены данные так же записываю в БД MSSQL пока локально. Для работы с БД использую EF + Code First. С текстовыми данными у меня вроде бы получилось. А вот с картинкой совсем не понимаю как быть. BLOB отметаю. Помогите реализовать. Мне необходима именно реализация, так как она у меня и хромает. Буду благодарен, если кто-то дополнит мой код для передачи картинок и сохранения их путей и тд.. (Контекст и регистрацию показывать не буду, что бы не нагромождать код).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сервер**
Модель:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Интерфейс хранилища и реализация:

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    Person Add(Person person);
    Person Get(Guid id);
    IEnumerable<Person> GetAll();
    void Remove(Guid id);
    bool Update(Person person);
}

public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private readonly PersonContext _personContext;


    public PersonRepository(PersonContext personContext)
    {
        _personContext = personContext;
    }


    public Person Add(Person person)
    {
        try
        {
             person.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            _personContext.Persons.Add(person);
            _personContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new Exception(err.Message);
        }
        return person;
    }


    public Person Get(Guid id)
    {
        return _personContext.Persons.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    }


    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            return _personContext.Persons.AsQueryable();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new Exception(err.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(Guid id)
    {

        try
        {
            Person employeeToRemove = new Person { Id = id };
            _personContext.Persons.Attach(employeeToRemove);
            _personContext.Persons.Remove(employeeToRemove);
            _personContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Сотрудника не существует или запись удалена!" + err.Message));
        } 
    }

    public bool Update(Person person)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    public IPersonRepository Person { get; set; }

    public PersonController(IPersonRepository person)
    {
        Person = person;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
        return Person.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
    public IActionResult GetById(Guid id)
    {
        var item = Person.Get(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Person person)
    {
        if (person == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        Person.Add(person);
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = person.Id }, person);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody] Person person)
    {
        //Do something
    }

    [HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Update([FromBody] Person item, string id)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(Guid id)
    {
        var todo = Person.Get(id);
        if (todo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Person.Remove(id);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }
}
```

**Клиент**
Получение всех данных и добавление пользователя.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    String urlAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverUriString"];

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindTodoList();
    }

    private void BindTodoList()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlAddress);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/person/").GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var employees = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Person>>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                grdEmployee.ItemsSource = employees;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlAddress);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var todo = new Person();

        todo.Name = txtName.Text;
        todo.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
        todo.Department = txtDepartment.Text;
        todo.Path = txtPath.Text;
        todo.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

        using (var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/person/", todo).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Employee Added");
                txtName.Text = "";
                txtLastName.Text = "";
                txtDepartment.Text = "";
                txtPath.Text = "";
                BindTodoList();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnShowAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindTodoList();

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindTodoList();
    }

    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // OpenFileDialog
    }

    public bool SendData(byte[] image)
    {
       // Не знаю что...
       return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, храните в базе только имя файла (а сам файл в некоторой папке /uploads/ - причём имя файла генерируйте сами, чтобы при загрузке Image1.jpg не перетирало предыдущий загруженный файл). В принципе, можно и в BLOB засунуть, если ваш вопрос увидит Майоров он наверное так и посоветует, будем считать, что можно и так и так - выбор на ваш вкус.

Во-вторых, можете почитать как грузятся файлы через Request.Files - тынц: https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/16.php - там уже готовый код для серверной части (Upload, который разбирает Request.Files и сохраняет принятые файлы на диск)

Глядя на ваш код думаю этих двух подсказок будет достаточно.

А, нет. Вот ещё одна. Сделайте ещё одну модель - UploadPersonRequest, нагляднее будет:

```
public class UploadPersonRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateTime { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Также просто [поищите на so по тегу c# и слову HttpPostedFileBase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+HttpPostedFileBase+) вопросы, будет вам образцом для вдохновения.

> Возникло несколько вопросов: Скажите пожалуйста, для данной модели
>   необходим свой репозиторий и контекст для Code First? Как потом
>   связать две таблицы, ведь основная у меня существует и мне необходимо
>   тянуть данные основные. Зачем еще одна модель?

Для данной модели не нужен ни свой репозиторий и его не надо тащить в EF Code First. Почитайте в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804912/213987) то, что я пишу про RegisterViewModel: видите там два поля пароля и проверку на их одинаковость? В базе же мы храним только один раз и не в явном виде, а хешированное и часто ещё - солёное.

С этой моделью точно такая же ситуация: этот класс - лишь группировка входных параметров, чтобы вы могли сделать единый .Validate (допустим, проверить, что число переданных файлов не ноль или скажем ровно 1).

И эти данные request мы после валидации отправим на сохранение частично в одно место (на диск сам файл) и частично в базу (там у вас будет модель Person, при этом вы можете как сделать это просто dto-объектом, так и навесить дополнительную логику - зависит от архитектуры). И вот для работы с БД вам нужен отдельный репозиторий и для работы с диском вам нужен отдельный репозиторий.

Разумеется, вы можете работать и отделив HttpPostedFileBase от модели, просто тогда у вас будет часть информации в одном месте, часть в другом месте и я считаю такой способ менее удобным, если у вас есть цельная модель и на неё можно писать цельные юнит-тесты.